# Displaying an embedded webpage doesn't work using iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I am building a classroom bulletin board (40" display). I want to be able to choose articles to display. The site is Django2 driven.

However, I can not get the content to display. All I get is an empty iframe. I've read some articles that say that this is blocked by most web servers as click stealing.

The only posts I find on the subject are either too simple or too old.

Can someone knowledgeable tell me if this is at all possible?

```
                {% with scheduledArticles|first as sArticle %}
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ sArticle.image }}" alt="">
                        <div class="card-header ml-auto">
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/{{ sArticle.qrcCodeImage }}" alt="" width="50">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">{{ sArticle.title }}</h4>
                            <iframe src="{{ sArticle.articleURL }}" width="100%">
                              <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endwith %}
```

(BTW, I am crediting the author, this shouldn't violate copyright.)

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long time the answer was literally right under my nose! (Always ;-)

IN the console of my web browser was the following message...

Refused to display 'https://www.w3schools.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

iFrames are USELESS with 3rd party content, as most of the sites block their usage!

So the quest continues, I know that sites like Flipboard display article snippets, but I still don't know how.